# Must Follow rules of FxCOP

Tags: .net, static-analysis, rules, fxcop, white-box

I´m using FxCOP and I want to know which are the most important rules or the rules that anybody can´t miss when using this tool.

I´m looking for some article or page with a list of rules that must be used in fxCop, this tool has a lot of rules and it's difficult to select only a few of them.

Comment: Question is opion-based and asks for off-site resources. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Generally: Enable all rules and when you get warned about a violation and the underlying root doesn't match your coding guideline or doesn't make sense in your project, than disable this specific rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend very much on what sort of applications and/or APIs you are creating.  If you're interested in general-purpose "must" or "should" use lists, you might want to start with the rule sets packaged for Visual Studio Code Analysis (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264925.aspx).  (N. B.: These include a few extra rules that aren't available in the free version of FxCop.)  The following two rule sets might be of particular interest:

- [Managed Minimum Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh748309.aspx)
- [Managed Recommended Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264893.aspx)

*(Same answer as on the Microsoft forum.)*